# How does storage virtualization help?

Tags: storage

I am trying to understand various types of virtualization techniques. The concept of Hardware virtualization/Virtual machine was simple enough.

However, I am struggling to understand the concept of storage virtualization. One definition I have found

> grouping the physical storage from multiple network storage devices so that it looks like a single storage device.

How does doing the above exactly help?

Basically, I want to understand what goal are we trying to achieve with storage virtualization?